# React : can't update my state with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i try to insert some data in my state, but when i try, i've got an error on user_email: "test@mail.com" : The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis

But i don't understand where am i supposed to put parenthesis. This is the code :

```
const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState({
    user_email: "",
    user_password: "",
  });


  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(refConnexionMail.current.value); 
    setUserLogin(
      ...userLogin,
      user_email: 'test@mail.com'
    )
    await POST(ENDPOINTS.USER_LOGIN, userLogin);
    // await GET(ENDPOINTS.USER_LOGIN)
    fetch("http://localhost:4200/api/auth/login")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  };
```

and this is the error :[image]

Then, i will replace "test@mail.com" by "refConnexionMail.current.value" which is the data i want to put in my state.

Comment: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis. Your setState should have parenthesis.

setUserLogin({
      ...userLogin,
      user_email: 'test@mail.com'
   })

Comment: On top of that, setState is a async operation. So better use callback when using setState.

Comment: Added an answer, comment was getting messy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis.

It has to have parenthesis here:

```
setUserLogin({
   ...userLogin,
   user_email: 'test@mail.com'
})
```

setState being an async operation, you may or may not have the right value for your POST method. So better do something like this.

```
setUserLogin((prevState) => {
     return {
        ...prevState,
        user_email: 'test@mail.com'
     }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
You have to put the parenthesis here

```
setUserLogin({
      ...userLogin,
      user_email: 'test@mail.com'
    })
```